Meaning of the p-value calculation for Kolmogorov-Smirnov test in KSTEST2 function in MATLAB
I am using the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test to determine if two samples of data derive from the same distribution or not.
I understand how the KS statistic is calculated: Basicly it's the maximum difference between the empirical CDF of the two samples.
The null hypothesis is that the samples are from the same distribution, so if the p-value is lower than alpha (say, alpha=0.05), we reject the null hypothesis and state that the two samples are from different distributions.
What i don't understand is how the p-value is calculated. I am using the MATLAB KSTEST2 function. the p-value calculations is (relavnt parts):
n      =  n1 * n2 /(n1 + n2);
lambda =  max((sqrt(n) + 0.12 + 0.11/sqrt(n)) * KSstatistic , 0);
j       =  (1:101)';
pValue  =  2 * sum((-1).^(j-1).*exp(-2*lambda*lambda*j.^2));
pValue  =  min(max(pValue, 0), 1);

Setting aside the max and min that are probably just making sure lambda isn't negative and p-valus isn't above 1 or under 0, I don't understand how and why the p-value is calculated this way.
Can anyone explain?
